# Create button programmatically monotouch

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uibutton, xamarin.ios

Hi all i'm trying to create a button dynamically via code,
but when i run the debugger the button isn't displayed in the simulator.

this is the code that i have written in the viewdidload metod

```
var button = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
            button.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(100f, 100f, 100f, 100f);
         button.SetTitle("click me", UIControlState.Normal);
```

i tried other code too for example :

```
UIButton button = new UIButton(UIButtonType.InfoDark); //BTN
button.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(59, 59, 59, 59);
```

i think that the problem is stupid but i can't find solution.
thank you

Answer (score 3):

You have to `Add` it to your `UIView` (`UIViewController`)

```
UIButton button = new UIButton(UIButtonType.InfoDark); //BTN
button.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(59, 59, 59, 59);
Add(button);
```

> [Add](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController.Add/p/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIView/)
>
> This is an alias for UIView.AddSubview, but uses the Add pattern as it allows C# 3.0 constructs to add subviews after creating the object.

Comment: is it possibile to use in an external .cs file?

Comment: @AndreaLoda You need to have a reference to the `UIView` (or `UIViewController`) that you are adding it to. i.e. `UIView.Add` `UIViewController.Add` `UIViewController.View.Add`

Answer (score 0):

You allocated your button but you didn't add it to your view. Try this

```
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

In Xamarin, would be

```
this.AddSubview(button);
```